# When updating an Android app does the APK need to be named the same as the original?

Tags: android, apk, google-play

I'm updating my app and I just wanted to know if the apk needs to be named the same as the original one that I uploaded. I'm pretty sure the answer is 'No', but just wanted to check as I can't find an explicit answer anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only things that *must* match the original app are the package name and the signing keystore. Other than that, you can change anything you want, including the name of the apk file (Google Play will rename it on its servers anyways).

You will also need to increment the version code (the version name may stay the same)

Comment: I just received this notice when I updated my app on Google Play: 'You need to use a different package name because "com.xxxx.yyyy" is already used by one of your other applications.' This is an update, so that information SHOULD be the same. The versioning numbers have been updated, so I'm at a loss as to why the apk is being refused.

Comment: can we change the package name as well?

Comment: No, you can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the key and the package name in your manifest should be same for each update , apk name should not matter.